# the array and loop program in c is working on one test case but not working on the other one

Tags: arrays, c, loops

The software tool is a repository of files, often the files for the source code of computer programs, with monitored access. Every change made to the source is tracked, along with who made the change, why they made it, and references to problems fixed, or enhancements introduced, by the change.
Software tools are essential for any form of distributed, collaborative development. Whether it is the history of a wiki page or large software development project, the ability to track each change as it was made, and to reverse changes when necessary can make all the difference between a well managed and controlled process and an uncontrolled ‘first come, first served’ system. It can also serve as a mechanism for due diligence for software projects.
In this problem we'll consider a simplified model of a development project. Let's suppose, that there are N source files in the project. All the source files are distinct and numbered from 1 to N.
The tool, that is used for maintaining the project, contains two sequences of source files. The first sequence contains the source files, that are ignored by the tool. If a source file is not in the first sequence, then it's considered to be unignored. The second sequence contains the source files, that are tracked by the tool. If a source file is not in the second sequence, then it's considered to be untracked. A source file can either be or not be in any of these two sequences.
Constraints:
1 ≤ T ≤ 100
1 ≤ M, K ≤ N ≤ 100
1 ≤ A1 < A2 < ... < AM ≤ N
1 ≤ B1 < B2 < ... < BK ≤ N
Input
The first line of the input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
The first line of the test case description contains three integers N, M and K denoting the number of source files in the project, the number of ignored source files and the number of tracked source files.
The second line contains M distinct integers denoting the sequence A of ignored source files. The sequence is strictly increasing.
The third line contains K distinct integers denoting the sequence B of tracked source files. The sequence is strictly increasing.
Output:
Print the number of the source files, that are both tracked and ignored, and the number of the source files, that are both untracked and unignored.

The test case that is working

```
INPUT (STDIN)
2
7 4 6
1 4 6 7
1 2 3 4 6 7
4 2 2
1 4
3 4
EXPECTED OUTPUT
4 1
1 1
```

The test case that is not working

```
INPUT (STDIN)
2
7 3 6
1 4 6 7
1 2 3 4 6 7
4 2 2
1 4
3 3
EXPECTED OUTPUT
3 1
2 3
```

The mandatory cases

```
KEYWORD
int a[m],b[k]
KEYWORD
while
KEYWORD
for
```

The complexity test case

```
CYCLOMATIC COMPLEXITY
9
TOKEN COUNT
245
NLOC
31
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int t, i;
  scanf("%d", &t);
  while (t--) {
    int n, m, k, c1 = 0, c2 = 0;
    scanf("%d%d%d", &n, &m, &k);
    int a[m], b[k], c[101];
    for (i = 0; i <= 101; i++)
      c[i] = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
      scanf("%d", &a[i]);
      c[a[i]]++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
      scanf("%d", &b[i]);
      c[b[i]]++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
      if (c[i] == 2) {
        c1++;
      }
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      if (c[i] == 0) {
        c2++;
      }
    }
    printf("%d %d\n", c1, c2);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At least this problem

**Writing outside array bounds**

Loop iterates 102 times to fill a 101 sized array.

```
    int a[m], b[k], c[101];
    for (i = 0; i <= 101; i++)
      c[i] = 0;
```

OP may want `for (i = 0; i < 101; i++)`